# Prefab object appearing correctly until instantiated

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the following code for a simple 2d game. The game is lit by a directional light at the moment, which lights both the background and the player.

```
public class BlockSpawner : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public GameObject blockPrefab; // a purple cube
        public Vector2 spawnSizeMinMax;
        private double _secondsBetweenSpawns = 0.5;
        private float _nextSpawnTime;
        private void Update()
        {
            if (Time.time > _nextSpawnTime)
            {
                _nextSpawnTime = (float) (Time.time + _secondsBetweenSpawns);
                float spawnSize = Random.Range(spawnSizeMinMax.x, spawnSizeMinMax.y);
                Vector3 spawnPosition =
                    new Vector3(
                        Random.Range(Player.screenHalfWidth - spawnSize, -Player.screenHalfWidth + spawnSize),
                        Player.screenHalfHeight + spawnSize,
                        5
                    );
                GameObject block = Instantiate(blockPrefab, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);

                block.transform.parent = transform;
                block.transform.localScale = Vector2.one * spawnSize;
                block.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 0, Random.Range(-20, 20)));
            }
        }
    }
```

When I drag the prefab onto the scene it appears as a 3d red cube. When I use this code to spawn it, it appears as a 2d black square and does not respond to lighting at all. In every other way it behaves as expected.

Is there some way to make it accept light? I've tried everything in the inspector.

Edit: Here are some screenshots

[image: screenshot of the problem]
[image: second screenshot of problem]

Comment: I don't see a reason this would happen. I can check for myself when I get to a computer with unity but you might need to include more information for anyone to answer the question.

Comment: Is the object maybe marked as [static](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StaticObjects.html) in the Inspector?

Comment: @derHugo It isn't marked as static. I have uploaded a screenshot in case that makes the problem obvious?

Comment: @Ruzihm I have uploaded a screenshot if that makes the problem clearer?

Comment: Please show the inspector while selecting the dragged-in square. I'm wondering if the spawned cubes are positioned in a way that the light can't shine on the camera-facing side of the cube, and I'd like to see how that one that's rendering as expected is positioned

Comment: @Ruzihm I've added another screenshot thanks. The cubes when spawned are 2 dimensional - I imagine that might have something to do with it?

Comment: Thanks, but it would be most helpful if you selected a dragged-in square that renders as you expect, like the purple one

Comment: @Ruzihm Yes! I meant to do that. I have uploaded it again.

Comment: I did just figure it out though, z-scale is 0 which makes it black. If I set it any higher it appears purple immediately. Do you know why that is? I reckon all 2d stuff must have a z-scale of 0.

Comment: @userqwert Ooh, great catch. It looks like the cause was visible in the code from the very start :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noticed, it's because you have a zero component in the scale. You should calculate the local scale so that no component is zero. You can do this by using `Vector3.one` instead of `Vector2.one` in your assignment:

```
block.transform.parent = transform;
block.transform.localScale = Vector3.one * spawnSize;
block.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 0, Random.Range(-20, 20)));
```

Having a zero-componented scale defies certain assumptions that the lighting calculations have when the engine is determining whether a surface is being hit by light or not.

Comment: Thanks for your help with this!